# What version of node.js for Visual Studio using Cordova tools?

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-cordova

I'm playing around with Visual Studio and Cordova. I get warnings that node is an old version. What version of node would you recommend?

Warning: using node version v0.12.2 which has been deprecated. Please upgrade to the latest node version available (v6.x is recommended).

Visual studio installed node version 0.12.2 and according to this page [https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/change-node-version](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/change-node-version/#install-a-newer-version-of-nodejs)/, that is the safest version to use. It mentions this:

To use Node.js version 4.x, make sure that your project uses Cordova CLI version 5.3.3 or later.

To use Node.js version 5.x, make sure that your project uses Cordova CLI version 5.4.1 or later

Answer (score 2):

> I get warnings that node is an old version. What version of node would you recommend?

`0.12.x` is the recommended version, because it's compatible with all versions of the Cordova CLI.

If the project builds and run correctly, you can ignore this warning.

Comment: By default, the VS TACO tools will use a sandboxed version of node.js to ensure compatibility with our tools. In VS 2015 this is version 0.12.x. You can change this setting in tools -> Options -> Tools for Apache Cordova, but be careful to use a node version that is compatible with the CLI you are targeting. (disclosure: I work on the Tools for Apache Cordova in Visual Studio)